# mysql_real_escape_string() completely removes string

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm escaping all the string parameters I receive from a php form like this:

```
$usr_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['usr_name']);
```

to avoid a few problems with SQL Injection.  But when I my string back from the function, I end up with nothing.

Also I keep getting this weird warning in my PHP log:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: A link to the server could not be established in /hermes/bosweb/web279/b2798/ipw.bankingforms/public_html/formAckResponse_controller.php on line 39
```

The host uses: PHP Version 4.4.7

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [PHP.net:](http://us.php.net/mysql-real-escape-string)

> **Note:** A MySQL connection is required
>   before using
>   `mysql_real_escape_string()` otherwise
>   an error of level `E_WARNING` is
>   generated, and `FALSE` is returned. If
>   `link_identifier` isn't defined, the
>   last MySQL connection is used.

In other words, you will have needed to connect to the MySQL database through `mysql_connect()` or `mysql_pconnect()` before you can use this function.

Comment: I've known to do this, but never knew why, exactly. Does the function run on the database server side? Or is this simply an API limitation?

Comment: It is run server-side, because MySQL's escaping depends on the character set currently in use by the server.