# Do i have to change all my htmlspecialchars ... ENT_QUOTES in mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, quotes, mysql-real-escape-string, htmlspecialchars

i wanted to protect my website from sql injections and other possible risks, so i changed all my sql queries by adding for each variable something like this :

```
 $getLid = htmlspecialchars($_GET[lid], ENT_QUOTES);
```

For my 50 files... But i have just seen that it might be my mistake : i should have added mysql_real_escape_string for any "input"...

Is it still better to use `mysql_real_escape_string` in this case, or the `ENT_QUOTES` works also? Do i have to restart again and add `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of my `htmlspecialchars(..., ENT_QUOTES);` ?

Edit :

Do you mean something like that?

```
$getLid = escape_string($str);

function escape_string($str){
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}
```

Edit n°2 :  the return statement does not work properly, would you know why?

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in … www/escape_file.php
>
> Access denied for user in … www/escape_file.php

Thanks

Comment: Your first mistake is to use `ext/mysql.` Read "How do I make my database queries secure from SQL injection?" on http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info.

Comment: @alexn  : thanks, any other ideas about my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lots of references to secure user inputs.  You can Google it, but I think you should write a class or a function in another php file like "escape.php" and then include that file to all of your 50 files. then use that for escaping. exmple:

```
include 'escape.php';
$str = escape_string($str);
```

So you can change your escaping function so easy just with changing a single file.
I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks do you mean something like in my edit? (my post above)

Comment: yeah. but you should write this code to another file and include it. then you can change all of your files by changing just a single file.

Comment: argh... thanks ok, ENT_QUOTES cannot somehow replace escape_string? if i have no choice, i'll replace all my files...

Comment: They are used for completely different things. htmlspecialchars() converts special HTML characters into entities so that they can be output without problems (or a risk of XSS), while mysql_real_escape_string() escapes sensitive SQL characters so interpolated queries can be performed without the risk of SQL injection. [Htmlspecialchars Or Mysql_real_escape_string](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=30091)

Comment: hi Siamak.A.M, sorry, but there is a problem with the return statement, it does not work properly, as in my edit above, would you have any idea about this? Thanks

Comment: Note that mysql must be a valid, open connection. This is needed because the escaping depends on the character set in use by the server. look at this links: [mysql_real_escape_string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) - [A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812779/mysql-real-escape-string-completely-removes-string)